# Breeze.js setting navigation property to null causes foreign key error

Tags: entity-framework-5, breeze

I have a model with a navigation property and associated foreign key property, like this:

```
public class Teacher {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Course {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? TeacherId { get; set; } // foreign key property
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

In client-side code, setting `course.Teacher(null)` causes `course.TeacherId` to get set to zero. On save, this causes a foreign key error in Entity Framework.

`course.TeacherId` needs to get set to null, not zero, for Entity Framework to save correctly.

Looking at the Breeze code, when a navigation property is set to null, the foreign key property is set to the default value of the *target object's key property*, which in the example above is the default value of `Teacher.Id` (which is zero). Instead, I think the foreign key property should be set to its *own* default value. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/pull/11) for this.

Comment: Joe, nice catch and thanks. I will be adding your fix to the next release.

Comment: @Jay Actually, would it be better to just set the foreign key property to null? I am thinking now that the default value will not necessarily be the null or "not set" value. I can update the pull request...

Comment: Actually, I think setting the foreign key to the default value is correct, otherwise you can end up causing a validation exception when the field is nonnullable. But I can be convinced if you have a good reason to believe otherwise.